# How to view transaction logs in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I need to view the transaction logs of a database on [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) in order to find a delete transaction and hopefully roll it back.

Unfortunately I have no clue where to start, and I'm finding it difficult to determine which are **good** articles on Google.

What should I do?

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31348/sql-server-contents-of-transaction-log-file-in-more-detail

Comment: Read this blog and know how to use fn_dblog() function to find deleted records in SQL Server http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/reading-sql-server-transaction-logs/

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-read-a-sql-server-transaction-log/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could use the undocumented

```
DBCC LOG(databasename, typeofoutput)
```

where typeofoutput:

```
0: Return only the minimum of information for each operation -- the operation, its context and the transaction ID. (Default)
1: As 0, but also retrieve any flags and the log record length.
2: As 1, but also retrieve the object name, index name, page ID and slot ID.
3: Full informational dump of each operation.
4: As 3 but includes a hex dump of the current transaction log row.
```

For example, **DBCC LOG(database, 1)**

You could also try fn_dblog.

For rolling back a transaction using the transaction log I would take a look at Stack Overflow post *[Rollback transaction using transaction log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065531/rollback-transaction-using-transaction-log)*.

Comment: Hi @kevchadders, I will try that. Thanks. to clarify, is it the last column that is the most recent?

Comment: Yes. run DBCC LOG(database, 1) and you should see the TransactionID (4th column) imcrement up in hex

Answer (score 20):

You can't read the transaction log file easily because that's not properly documented. There are basically two ways to do this. Using undocumented or semi-documented database functions or using third-party tools.

Note: This only makes sense if your database is in full recovery mode.

SQL Functions:

DBCC LOG and fn_dblog - more details [here](http://killspid.blogspot.com/2006/07/using-fndblog.html) and [here](http://www.confio.com/logicalread/sql-server-dbcc-log-command-details-and-example/).

Third-party tools:

[Toad for SQL Server](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-sql-server/) and [ApexSQL Log](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx).

You can also check out several other topics where this was discussed:

- *[Rollback transaction using transaction log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065531/rollback-transaction-using-transaction-log)*
- *[SQL Server Transaction Log Explorer/Analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789443/sql-server-transaction-log-explorer-analyzer)*
- *[Read the log file (*.LDF) in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767054)*

Answer (score 5):

I accidentally deleted a whole bunch of data in the wrong environment and this post was one of the first ones I found.

Because I was simultaneously panicking and searching for a solution, I went for the first thing I saw - [ApexSQL Logs](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx), which was $2000 which was an acceptable cost.

However, I've since found out that [Toad for Sql Server](http://software.dell.com/products/toad-for-sql-server/) can generate undo scripts from transaction logs and it is only $655.

Lastly, found an even cheaper option [SysToolsGroup Log Analyzer](http://www.systoolsgroup.com/sql-log-analyzer.html) and it is only $300.

Comment: `SysToolsGroup Log Analyzer` costs $300 for a personal license and you arent allowed to use it for commercial purpose for that you need a Business license and that costs $799.