# Finding the Insert Transaction Date on SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

A record inserted to a table good while ago with no datetime. Is there any way when this transaction has been done based on the id?

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do it by importing/digging through the log files and extracting the LSN of the event...

Here's a good link on [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9586966/how-to-read-trn-file-data) attempt it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, unless you have a `datetime` column in your table to record the actual time of insertion; there is actually no way to find that out.

You can run `DBCC` command to check `Transaction Log` (`DBCC LOG ('DB_NAME')`) but not sure how much helpful that would be.

You can probably use [Server-Side Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293613.aspx) but have never used that personally.

Comment: Server Traces are only good when you are trying to catch a problem as it happens, No good to diagnose problems from past :)

Answer (score 1):

Nope there is nothing in Sql server that can get you information about that insert unless you have CDC enabled or some sort of Audit Trigger on that table.

Having said all this you do have the Log file which logs details about all the operations in Sql Server. You can use some Third-Party tools to view that Sql Server Transaction Log.

Some of the tools are

1. [`Red Gate SQL Log Rescue`](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-log-rescue/)
2. [`Apex Sql Discovery and recovery tool`](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx)