# How to find the data refresh and load times of various tables in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can anyone tell me how to find the data refresh and load times of various tables in sql server 2008?

Regards,
C

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional Column (for ex. "RefreshDate") in you tables and set it's `Default Value or Binding` to `getdate()`. So every time you update or insert any data, it will show the exact data refresh or load time.

Comment: Hi Shohin, thanks but i cant do any update on the table as i am doing some audit on the DB tables. Is there any other way to find out these details without updating the table?Processes Running against thetable, Frequency, Average Duration of the process, Account Used, Description of the process, Source of Data, Data Refresh/Load Times, Process that Updates the Data.

Comment: Well in this case you can view DB Log. Check out [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008)