# How to recover table from the laste updated query in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have accidentally executed an update query in SQL, I need to recover the changes. No backup has taken for the DB. After the update query I have not executed any subsequent queries.

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: If you're not working in a transaction and you don't have backups, I'm afraid you can't do a recovery.

Comment: Oracle has flashback which can be used if enabled on your database. If you're using another RDBMS then I don't know of a way.

Comment: I am using MSSQL.Please help as it is very urgent.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Microsoft SQL Server. With no backup, and outside of a transaction I am afraid you are out of luck.

Comment: Depends on the RDBMS and options set on the database set up.

Comment: Since he said SQL, i am assuming sql server.

Comment: It may be SQL Server, but SQL is also the name of the language used for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc.

Comment: Yes. I know that. I have updated my answer to be MS SQL specific. How about removing the down vote?

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking out the transactional logs referred to in [this](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-server-data-recovery-from-update-and-delete/) article. I have not tried this personally, but this is the angle that I would look into if I was in the same position.

It may also be worth looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008) stack overflow answer.