# Sql Server 2012 Read Transactional Log

Tags: logging, sql-server-2012, transactional

I have an application that uses sql server database. One of the columns in my table has modified and somehow I can't see anything in the application logs. There is no audit log operation at the database. Is it possible to find out when this update operation did execute? Can I get this information from transactional log?

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008, I think it may provide some help here.

Comment: @Elliveny Link you posted is not going to help. Its talking about dbcc loginfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of the columns in my table has modified and somehow I can't see anything in the application logs.

There is `no Documented way` of reading the transaction log file. But you can use undocumented command `fn_dblog` to read the transaction log file. Its also not guaranteed to provide you all information and if log that was holding the transaction information is committed and re utilized there is no way fn_dblog would give you any information.

You can read output of transaction log and understand its meaning by taking help of [How to read and interpret SQL Server Logs](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/)

You can use some third party tool to read transaction log.

Other help is Default trace. Please note that default trace file is overwritten after it crosses certain size so if event happened couple of days backs information might have been overwritten. Please use below query and see if this is of any help [Source](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server---the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/)

```
SELECT  TE.name ,

        v.subclass_name ,

        DB_NAME(t.DatabaseId) AS DBName ,

        T.NTDomainName ,

        t.NTUserName ,

        t.HostName ,

        t.ApplicationName ,

        t.LoginName ,

        t.Duration ,

        t.StartTime ,

        t.ObjectName ,

        CASE t.ObjectType

          WHEN 8259 THEN 'Check Constraint'

          WHEN 8260 THEN 'Default (constraint or standalone)'

          WHEN 8262 THEN 'Foreign-key Constraint'

          WHEN 8272 THEN 'Stored Procedure'

          WHEN 8274 THEN 'Rule'

          WHEN 8275 THEN 'System Table'

          WHEN 8276 THEN 'Trigger on Server'

          WHEN 8277 THEN '(User-defined) Table'

          WHEN 8278 THEN 'View'

          WHEN 8280 THEN 'Extended Stored Procedure'

          WHEN 16724 THEN 'CLR Trigger'

          WHEN 16964 THEN 'Database'

          WHEN 16975 THEN 'Object'

          WHEN 17222 THEN 'FullText Catalog'

          WHEN 17232 THEN 'CLR Stored Procedure'

          WHEN 17235 THEN 'Schema'

          WHEN 17475 THEN 'Credential'

          WHEN 17491 THEN 'DDL Event'

          WHEN 17741 THEN 'Management Event'

          WHEN 17747 THEN 'Security Event'

          WHEN 17749 THEN 'User Event'

          WHEN 17985 THEN 'CLR Aggregate Function'

          WHEN 17993 THEN 'Inline Table-valued SQL Function'

          WHEN 18000 THEN 'Partition Function'

          WHEN 18002 THEN 'Replication Filter Procedure'

          WHEN 18004 THEN 'Table-valued SQL Function'

          WHEN 18259 THEN 'Server Role'

          WHEN 18263 THEN 'Microsoft Windows Group'

          WHEN 19265 THEN 'Asymmetric Key'

          WHEN 19277 THEN 'Master Key'

          WHEN 19280 THEN 'Primary Key'

          WHEN 19283 THEN 'ObfusKey'

          WHEN 19521 THEN 'Asymmetric Key Login'

          WHEN 19523 THEN 'Certificate Login'

          WHEN 19538 THEN 'Role'

          WHEN 19539 THEN 'SQL Login'

          WHEN 19543 THEN 'Windows Login'

          WHEN 20034 THEN 'Remote Service Binding'

          WHEN 20036 THEN 'Event Notification on Database'

          WHEN 20037 THEN 'Event Notification'

          WHEN 20038 THEN 'Scalar SQL Function'

          WHEN 20047 THEN 'Event Notification on Object'

          WHEN 20051 THEN 'Synonym'

          WHEN 20549 THEN 'End Point'

          WHEN 20801 THEN 'Adhoc Queries which may be cached'

          WHEN 20816 THEN 'Prepared Queries which may be cached'

          WHEN 20819 THEN 'Service Broker Service Queue'

          WHEN 20821 THEN 'Unique Constraint'

          WHEN 21057 THEN 'Application Role'

          WHEN 21059 THEN 'Certificate'

          WHEN 21075 THEN 'Server'

          WHEN 21076 THEN 'Transact-SQL Trigger'

          WHEN 21313 THEN 'Assembly'

          WHEN 21318 THEN 'CLR Scalar Function'

          WHEN 21321 THEN 'Inline scalar SQL Function'

          WHEN 21328 THEN 'Partition Scheme'

          WHEN 21333 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 21571 THEN 'Service Broker Service Contract'

          WHEN 21572 THEN 'Trigger on Database'

          WHEN 21574 THEN 'CLR Table-valued Function'

          WHEN 21577

          THEN 'Internal Table (For example, XML Node Table, Queue Table.)'

          WHEN 21581 THEN 'Service Broker Message Type'

          WHEN 21586 THEN 'Service Broker Route'

          WHEN 21587 THEN 'Statistics'

          WHEN 21825 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 21827 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 21831 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 21843 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 21847 THEN 'User'

          WHEN 22099 THEN 'Service Broker Service'

          WHEN 22601 THEN 'Index'

          WHEN 22604 THEN 'Certificate Login'

          WHEN 22611 THEN 'XMLSchema'

          WHEN 22868 THEN 'Type'

          ELSE 'Hmmm???'

        END AS ObjectType

FROM    [fn_trace_gettable](CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), ( SELECT TOP 1

                                                            value

                                                    FROM    [fn_trace_getinfo](NULL)

                                                    WHERE   [property] = 2

                                                  )), DEFAULT) T

        JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id

        JOIN sys.trace_subclass_values v ON v.trace_event_id = TE.trace_event_id

                                            AND v.subclass_value = t.EventSubClass

WHERE   TE.name IN ( 'Object:Created', 'Object:Deleted', 'Object:Altered' )

                -- filter statistics created by SQL server                                         

        AND t.ObjectType NOT IN ( 21587 )

                -- filter tempdb objects

        AND DatabaseID <> 2

                -- get only events in the past 24 hours

        AND StartTime > DATEADD(HH, -24, GETDATE())

ORDER BY t.StartTime DESC ;
```

Comment: Does this select statement get only DDL operations?

Comment: The select statement give information about Objects that are being altered. Please read link embedded in source statement in the answer. You would get complete details about what the query does