# Equivalent of Tailing a MongoDB Operation Log in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

MongoDB has something called an [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) which you can [tail](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/tailing-mongodb-oplog-sharded-clusters) to read/replay all operations (insert, update, delete, etc) that happen to a database. I am looking to do something similar in SQL Server but have been unable to find anything equivalent. Does anything similar to this exist in SQL Server, and more specifically, SQL Azure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what version of SQL Server your running, I believe Change Data Capture will cover your need.  There are built in functions that will allow you to query all the changes that took place on CDC enabled tables.  I've included a link from the [Microsoft TechNet library](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510744(v=sql.105).aspx) and another from a [blog](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/) that provides an introduction to CDC.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome. Looks like CDC is not available in Azure (yet, at least), but there is another alternative which is available with v12 databases: Change Tracking: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875.aspx

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server has the Transaction Log facility that does just that - record all transactions in order to be able to rollback up to a certain point.

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507509/how-to-view-transaction-logs-in-sql-server-2008) you can use `DBCC LOG(databasename, typeofoutput)` to access that information

Comment: Parsing the transaction log seems very cryptic. Are there any tools or libraries to make this easier (in code)?

Comment: You could run a trace - that will show statements nicer. But at a quite heavy cost.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to accomplish it is [SQL Server profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx). Other ways are given [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/). You can save SQL Server Profiler output to file or table then use other means to read it.