# Is it possible to get the queries executed in the past?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)

I want somehow to get the history of the executed queries on SQL Server 2008 R2. Let's say I run the query:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE
```

Is it logged somewhere? Can I see the queries that were executed on the server?

I want to check if a stored procedure or any other automated task was executed at a specific time.

Answer (score 3):

Will [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/03/sql-server-2005-last-ran-query-recently-ran-query/) help?

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

and as pointed by anio [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: I've already seen that but it didn't help me. It returns the latest more often executed queries form the cache of the Sql Server.

Comment: sys.dm_exec_sql_text is not available in sql server 2000 and available from 2005

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '.' with old SqlServer 2008-r2