# Save a query in an access database from C#

Tags: c#, oledb, jet

Since MS Access can save a query in the database file I assume there is a way to do this programmatically from C#. Any idea how?

Comment: What do you mean by "Save a Query"? Save the SQL that you sent to the database, then run it later?

Comment: Yes. In MS Access for instance you have a list of tables and a list of queries. These queries can only be stored in the database file since when you close it and re open it they're still there.

Comment: you find it or not yet ?? @Juan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible. SQL Server doesn't record queries, according to [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)
(Not sure about other databases, but I imagine they all work the same way)

You'd need to manually store them as a varchar in a table

Comment: But then how do you explain MS Access storing queries in the database file? SQL Server is different than the JET Engine.