# Is there any way to view the last run sql query in sql server managment studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have run a query a few days before but  its lost now I did not save it can you please help me whether we can find the last run query in sql server managament studio.

Comment: If SQL Server hasn't been restarted, you may be able to find the query in the plan cache. [Since I noticed the duplicate, I transferred my answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18018743/61305).

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [SSMS Tools](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) in the future.
Among several other features, it also keeps a history of queries run.