# Emulation of Java application on PHP

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, sql-server

### Scenario:

We have a PHP/MySQL based corporate web portal and a separate MS SQL database on a remote server which could be accesed by a 3rd party vendor Java application(web client communicating with the MSSQL database).

### Requirement:

I would like to get rid of that Java application and transfer all functionalities to the PHP web portal and I need to figure out the queries as I don't have the source code of that Java application and there is no way to reach the vendor to ask.

Is there any way I can capture the queries that Java application is sending so I can use those in my PHP scripts?

> Maybe tracing last queries from MSSQL somehow? Or
>
> Somehow see what the Java application emits to the database in some way?

Comment: Do you have access to the MSSQL server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes, I do, full access

Comment: Then take a look at the link there are a couple options for logging queries coming into the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can log incoming queries coming into the server ([How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)) you are still going to rewrite most of the queries as I'm sure most of them will be dynamic. You will simply see the end result in the log like this:

```
select * from users where id=5
```

While in the php code it will be a mysqli or pdo function that binds the 5 value to a prepared statement. So you will have to figure out why or how the java application came up with the query it did.