# How can get the stored procedure execution logs?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know that how many times it was executed from `execution_count` in `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`.

But how these values are calculated?

Is there any way to know how these values get calculated?

I want whole log when the stored procedure was  first time executed to till `last_execution_time` logs.

Answer (score 2):

The statictics are reset each time the server restarts, and the DMV is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280701.aspx

Comment: Hi @ErikEj , how  this `execution_count` get calculated? I mean somewhere sp execution `datetime`must  be stored ? So I want the whole log when- when the sp was executed and where this info is Stored?

Comment: SQL Server does not log query executions in the way you want (without use of Profiler, 3rd party tools or a roll your own solution).  See this previous discussion for more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio.