# How to see the history of executed scripts and their execution time and counts in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to find the execution time and execution count of the script ran in my sql server.

I have added, for example, /*** searchThisString ***/ on every executed script. And then I use the following code to find them out.

```
SELECT  dest.text, deqs.last_execution_time, deqs.execution_count 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > '<time>'
        AND dest.text LIKE '%<searchThisString>%';
```

However, there is one case that this code failed. If a script only consist of 'update' queries, the above code fails to find it out:

For example,

```
example_script.sql

/*searchThisString*/
update <table> set colA = 'A' where colB = 'B'
```

Then the above code will fail to find this executed script out.

**Update:**
I have just found that sys.dm_exec_cached_plans can actually find all the executed scripts. However, it does not have the last_execution_time and execution_count information of the executed scripts.

I have tried to join it with sys.dm_exec_query_stats using the following code (but it does not work either). I think because sys.dm_exec_query_stats does not have this executed query, so it return 'null' for the last_execution_time and 'null' for execution_count when I join them up.

```
SELECT  dest.text, deqs.last_execution_time, deqs.execution_count 
FROM    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS decp
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(decp.plan_handle) AS dest
LEFT JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats As deqs
ON decp.plan_handle = deqs.plan_handle
WHERE   deqs.last_execution_time > '<time>'
        AND dest.text LIKE '%<searchThisString>%';
```

**Update2:**
Here is the result:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: The solution I found on your suggested post does not actually solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I executed below script repeatedly

```
/***text***/

update test1 set name ='a'
where name ='test1'


update test1 set name='b'
where name='test2'
```

and then i executed below script to see stats..

```
select txt.text,st.execution_count,st.total_worker_time 
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats st
cross apply
sys.dm_exec_sql_text(st.sql_handle) txt
```

I could see output,even though there are only update statements..

[image]

Further,you can see from above snip,comments are not captured.I recommend checking for actual scripts instead of comments and further wrap,it up in a stored proc to see entire batch more clearly

I could see no issues with your query with exception of where clause..

[image]

Comment: Thansk. The reason I search the comment instead of search the query is that I want to search a batch of scripts that have the same 'keyword' in the comment. I can see that dm_exec_cached_plans saves the scripts and the comment as well, while dm_exec_query_stats saves the scripts but without comments. I believe joining these two table is the solution. However, I can't find a 'common' key between them when I attempt to join them. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks very much. Like I said, it can show the 'select' query (just like what's shown in your testing result). But it can't show the 'update' query. Please refer to my 'update2',

Answer (score -1):

Use the [SQL Server profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx) to see queries executed.

Also see [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Let me take at a look at this SQL Server Profiler.