# How to know the latest stored procedure affecting a rows of a table and when?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a temp table that is affected by various Stored procedures and wanted to know what the latest SP that affected the table and when.

There is some internal log or query that can bring me an approximate result in SQL server?

**Ex:**

Here `Temporary_summ` is my table and below is the format i am expecting..

```
 tablename            spname              lastaccessedtime
temporary_summ --- sp_math_cal --------- 2016-05-30 12:05:22

temporary_summ --- sp_weather_calc ---- 2016-05-30 12:06:34
```

Comment: Don't you think that would be an incredible amount of overhead to impose on all people implementing SQL Server databases, just on the off chance that someone will want this data? And then think about other pieces of data that *some* people might also want included, beyond what *your* requirements are. Should everyone be penalised for every possible meta-query that anyone might want to write in the future? In general, if you want something in SQL, you have to implement it and explicitly pay the price.

Comment: I agree, but in this case I think the re-use , if a User start a SP and the same is the last run I do not need  execute  she, only recovery the data, which was my initial idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the activity on a server using **SQL Server Profiler**.

It creates a log **since you start running it**. It is just for capture when needed (Ex.: debugging), so it doesn't consume the server resources.

[image]

Comment: Did not know this feature, thanks for the tip , however I can do this using sql ?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio