# How to view SQL Server query logs like MySQL general query logs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, logging, ssms

Can we view logs of all queries in SQL Server like MySQL general query logs?
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Yes.. Similar functionality comes with Sql Profiler https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
You can try a query like below

```
SELECT  *
    --use only text to see relevant query information
FROM    
  sys.dm_exec_query_stats stats
CROSS APPLY 
  sys.dm_exec_sql_text(stats.sql_handle) 
 -- Note that this is a function which takes in sql_handle as parameter
```

EDIT: You can see a similar question on DBA SO site
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/can-i-see-historical-queries-run-on-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query below can show simple transaction query logs:

```sql
SELECT Operation, [Begin Time], [End Time] 
FROM fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
```

This is how it looks like below:

[image]