# SQL Statements Log in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, logging

I have a need to pull all the recently executed SQL statements from SQL Server. What is the log file and location that I need to look for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see query history in SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)

Comment: It was asked many times, Please try to search before asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
SELECT B.TEXT AS [Query], A.execution_count [Count], A.last_execution_time AS [Time]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS A
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(A.sql_handle) AS B
ORDER BY A.last_execution_time DESC
```