# How to get historical run for a stored procedure with parameters for SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

How to get historical run details for a stored procedure with parameters values in a run for a SQL Server database?

For ex. if the `sp_getcustomerbyid` stored procedure is run in the database earlier with parameter 5, i.e `sp_getcustomerbyid 5`, I need this information.

How do we get this complete information `sp_getcustomerbyid 5`? It s not a duplicate, we don't have answers for fetching parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicate question of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio)?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Am exactly looking for stored procedure and not query. Sp with parameters