# Get executed SQL Query entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using: Entity Framework in .net 8.

I have code like this:

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql,
params)
```

Is it possible to get exact SQL that will be or was executed? I need it to store it in audit, I know that I can enable logging in EF but logged SQLs are not the same as executed and I need it in that part of the code so that I can add some metadata and put exact executed query in my audit datbaase.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this is the right approach for what you are searching but getting the queries you execute could be accessed via an interceptor. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

Comment: sql server should already doing most of this for you.

cant you just use the existing logs somehow?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio

Also if you are using EF and not using the features of EF then I would suggest using something like Dapper instead, just less overhead and you run SQL directly.

Comment: Also check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/auditing-overview?view=azuresql

Comment: Ähm the exact sql should be in the sql variable here? I'm pretty sure EF will not fiddle with raw sql in any way.

Comment: @Ralf query will be a bit different, there is whole logic to change it in EF. Changes are subtle but it does some magic with parameters and thats why sql itself is a bit different.

Comment: @Netferret I'm using features of EF but also need to execute stored procedure with some parameters and I would like this execution stored in my audit DB as well. The business need for that is a bit different and it is not important, basically question is: how to get exact SQL that is executed from within .net program that uses EF at this stage of program execution, thanks! :)

Comment: Why can the stored procedure itself not log the parameters it is called with, into the audit?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the easiest way to do this is actually with a trigger then when it inserts etc then  you can pass the data into an audit table.

something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER YourTriggerName
ON YourTableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @EventData XML;
SET @EventData = EVENTDATA();

INSERT INTO YourAuditTable (EventDateTime, EventType, EventData)
VALUES (GETDATE(), @EventData.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/EventType)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)'), CAST(@EventData AS NVARCHAR(MAX)));
END;
```